# Test a function resolve and reject

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Running a test using Jest and Enzyme. The test is passing at the moment but Some of the lines were covered when i ran a npm test coverage, but the last few lines are missing

```js
patchSourceEntity = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let SourceEntityBody = {
      FirmID: this.props.FirmId,
      Name: this.state.Name,
      ShortName: this.state.ShortName,
      SourceEntityTypeID: this.state.SourceEntityTypeID ? this.state.SourceEntityTypeID.value : null
    };

    fetch(`${this.props.services.MasterDB.URL}/SOURCE_ENTITY?id=${this.props.entityToEdit}`, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': this.props.services.MasterDB.subscription_key,
        DDHFirm: this.props.user.DDHFirm,
        'x-universal-firm': this.props.FirmId
      },
      method: 'PATCH',
      credentials: 'include',
      body: JSON.stringify(SourceEntityBody)
    })
      .then(res => {
        return validationManager.ResolveHTTPResponse(res, 'Request Successful', 'Request Failed', false);
      })
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.error) {
          resolve();
        } else {
          reject();
        }
      });
  });
};
```

I mock the function :

and called the function:

```js
const patchSourceEntity = jest.fn(() => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve();
  });
});
```

```
expect(wrapper.find('SourceEntityForm').instance().patchSourceEntity()).toBeDefined()
```

What else could i added in my test  in order to get it covered 100 %

Comment: If you're mocking the function, what exactly do you think you're testing?

Comment: replace something we dont control with something we do -  such as capture calls, or set return values

Comment: That's why you'd use mocking in general, but if you're mocking the thing you're testing, *what's left?*

Comment: im new to testing, just wondering how i would test then(response => {
      if(!response.error) {
        resolve();
      } else {
        reject(); for example

Comment: The `fetch` function would be a more useful one to mock.